# Does line feature have one or two dimensions?

Tags: features, gis-principle, dimensions

In the coursera class [fundamentals of gis](https://www.coursera.org/learn/gis) it's said that lines are one-dimensional feature and polygons are two-dimensional.
Is this correct? if the line has a curvature two dimensions are needed to represent it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a line is a single segment connected by two points.  It has one dimension - length.

A linestring is made by joining several lines. Each of the lines have a single dimension, however, because the joined lines can change direction, they now have a second dimension - length and width, much like a polygon.

If you think of a simple curve, such as an arc of a circle, it has length and radius.  Also two dimensions.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I may have to change my mind on this.  After further reading, it appears that a curve can be described as having only one dimension.

From [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dimensionality):

> The dimension of an object is a topological measure of the size of its
>   covering properties. Roughly speaking, it is the number of coordinates
>   needed to specify a point on the object.

If a curve follows a particular function `f(x)` then you only need one dimension to describe a point's position on that curve, the distance from the start of the curve.

Here's a similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5063382/1500125).

And here's a discussion on a [physics forum](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-can-a-curve-be-one-dimensional.593124/) on the topic.

Comment: And here's what Wikipedia knows about dimensions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension.

Comment: Thanks @user30184.  I actually meant to add the wiki link to my answer.